# youcompleteme introspect names for python

Tags: python, vim, python-jedi

I have installed youcompleteme in vim along with Jedi.  I am able to get the completions to work when starting a declaration from module namespaces or names/variables in my current file.  The issue is that once I "dot" a "local" name which is not a module I get no suggestions.

In the following lines the first one shows completion after the dot. But the second line does not offer anything after the dot.  I assume because the name "main_grid" is not fully known to YCM due to not "processing" the line above in order to understand what type of object main_grid is.

```
main_grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
main_grid.setColumnStretch(0, 3)
```

Ideally, in the second line, I would have all the QtGui.QGridLayout methods available after typing "main_grid."

Is this possible?

**Update** with some vim outputs:

*:set omnifunc*

```
omnifunc=youcompleteme#OmniComplete
```

*:mes* has a number of these:

```
AttributeError: 'MergedNamesDict' object has no attribute 'get'
AttributeError: 'MergedNamesDict' object has no attribute 'get'
AttributeError: 'MergedNamesDict' object has no attribute 'get'
AttributeError: 'MergedNamesDict' object has no attribute 'get'
AttributeError: 'MergedNamesDict' object has no attribute 'get'
AttributeError: 'MergedNamesDict' object has no attribute 'get'
AttributeError: 'MergedNamesDict' object has no attribute 'get'
AttributeError: 'MergedNamesDict' object has no attribute 'get'
AttributeError: 'MergedNamesDict' object has no attribute 'get'
AttributeError: 'MergedNamesDict' object has no attribute 'get'
AttributeError: 'MergedNamesDict' object has no attribute 'get'
AttributeError: 'MergedNamesDict' object has no attribute 'get'
```

*:version*

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Apr 23 2015 11:27:15)
Included patches: 1-712
Compiled by Arch Linux
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +cscope          +folding         +menu            +netbeans_intg   -sniff           +virtualedit
+arabic          +cursorbind      -footer          +mksession       +path_extra      +startuptime     +visual
+autocmd         +cursorshape     +fork()          +modify_fname    +perl            +statusline      +visualextra
+balloon_eval    +dialog_con_gui  +gettext         +mouse           +persistent_undo -sun_workshop    +viminfo
+browse          +diff            -hangul_input    +mouseshape      +postscript      +syntax          +vreplace
++builtin_terms  +digraphs        +iconv           +mouse_dec       +printer         +tag_binary      +wildignore
+byte_offset     +dnd             +insert_expand   +mouse_gpm       +profile         +tag_old_static  +wildmenu
+cindent         -ebcdic          +jumplist        -mouse_jsbterm   +python          -tag_any_white   +windows
+clientserver    +emacs_tags      +keymap          +mouse_netterm   -python3         -tcl             +writebackup
+clipboard       +eval            +langmap         +mouse_sgr       +quickfix        +terminfo        +X11
+cmdline_compl   +ex_extra        +libcall         -mouse_sysmouse  +reltime         +termresponse    -xfontset
+cmdline_hist    +extra_search    +linebreak       +mouse_urxvt     +rightleft       +textobjects     +xim
+cmdline_info    +farsi           +lispindent      +mouse_xterm     +ruby            +title           +xsmp_interact
+comments        +file_in_path    +listcmds        +multi_byte      +scrollbind      +toolbar         +xterm_clipboard
+conceal         +find_in_path    +localmap        +multi_lang      +signs           +user_commands   -xterm_save
+cryptv          +float           +lua             -mzscheme        +smartindent     +vertsplit       -xpm
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "/etc/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/inclu
de -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I
/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0
/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/includ
e/libpng16 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong
 --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-E -Wl
,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE  -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vi
m   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0
 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype  -lSM -lICE -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -lncurses -lelf -lnsl
 -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl  -L/usr/lib -llua -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-ne
eded,-z,relro -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -lperl -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -
lpthread -lc -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic   -lruby -lpthre
ad -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm  -L/usr/lib
```

Comment: Could you please post the following: `:set omnifunc`, `:mes`, `:version`.

Comment: Somehow after restarting vim, "dot" self now gives suggestions.  However, the issue is still persisting for other "local" names.

Comment: Probably a Jedi bug, just add it to Jedi's issue tracker and maybe try the latest dev branch of Jedi.